# Remove query string parameter and place it into path

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a page that I am trying to format in such a way that it will not contain a question mark in the URL.

For example, the following URLs are present:

```
https://example.com/report?rid=183
https://example.com/report?rid=675
```

The ideal behaviour is to have these readable in the following way (.php has already been removed as a file extension)

```
https://example.com/report/183
https://example.com/report/675
```

Current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: So you need to capture not only one part, but two parts of the requested path. Since you already succeeded with the first one you also are able to apply the same logic to the second one, we have to assume. So it is unclear what your actual issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/report/([0-9]*)$ $1/report?rid=$2 [NC,L]   ===> Note you may need to scape "?", that's why I used "\?"
```

Explanation:

- The "(.*)" will catch "https://example.com".
- The "([0-9]*)" will catch the id.
- The rewrite rules just appends both groups.

  - $1 = https://example.com
  - $2 = 183
  - $1/report?rid=$2 = https://example.com/report?rid=183

Comment: However, there are other pages in this section.  I don't want all of them to be caught in this, only the /report page.  Also, I'm a but confused as to how this works (I.e. how it catches specific URLs and not others, and how it will process.  There will also be other pages that will need this treatment, for example "/players/playerA" will need the same treatment.

Comment: Just play around with the regular expression. ^(.*)\?rid=(.*)$ will match every url. Something like ^(.*)/report\?rid=(.*)$ will match any url with "report" at the end and before a ?. If you need a rule for "players" or "playerA", again, play with the regular expression.

Comment: I've attempted to implement this, however attempting to access https://example.com/report/183 results in a 404 error.

Comment: But, don't you want the user accessing https://example.com/report?rid=183, and then Apache rewrites it in the background to https://example.com/report/183? And second, if https://example.com/report/183 throws a 404, it means your server can't find that path.

Comment: I want the user accessing /report/183 and apache rewriting to report.php?rid=183 in the background.

Comment: I got you wrong. The way you ask this should have been I think "I want URL X to be rewritten to Y". So, that said, just put the rule I gave you in the other way around. I will edit my response

Comment: I've attempted to add this code into my .htaccess file, and it has no effect.  Attempting to access https://example.com/report/183 yields a 404 error.  My .htaccess file - http://prntscr.com/sqnds2

Comment: I think you are missing PT as part of the options. Put PT along with NC and L. PT means past through.

Comment: Well, before doing that, let me ask you, is Apache in front of your web server?

Comment: Apache IS my web server.

Comment: Bad wording. Sorry. Meant to say what do you have behind Apache?